# big pagefile for a windows system with low RAM

Tags: windows, virtual-memory, pagefile

My Windows Server 2012 - 64 bit has nothing more than 4 GB of RAM.
Unfortunately I am in need to open and keep in memory files of around 40 GB. To make sure this happens can I just increase the size of the 'pagefile.sys' up to let's say 50 GB? 
I will obviously place it in the disk where this space is really available.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, there is a tutorial [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2013/01/07/how_2d00_to_2d00_change_2d00_the_2d00_size_2d00_of_2d00_virtual_2d00_memory_2d00_pagefile_2d00_sys_2d00_on_2d00_windows_2d00_8_2d00_or_2d00_windows_2d00_server_2d00_2012.aspx)

1. On the Keyboard Press the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then click `System` in the popup menu
2. Tap or click `Advanced system settings`. You might be asked for an admin password or to confirm your choice.
3. On the `Advanced` tab, under `Performance`, tap or click `Settings`.
4. Tap or click the `Advanced` tab, and then, under `Virtual memory`, tap or click `Change`.
5. Clear the `Automatically manage paging file size for all drives` check box.
6. Under `Drive [Volume Label]`, tap or click the drive that contains the paging file you want to change.
7. Tap or click `Custom size`, enter a new size in megabytes in the `Initial size (MB)` or `Maximum size (MB)` box, tap or click `Set`, and then tap or click `OK`.

Be aware this drive will be significantly affected in performance whilst reading and writing this amount to a page file. It may be worth upgrading your RAM as high as possible, or using a secondary hard drive or SSD.